# What volume of helium at standard ambient pressure and temperature is required to lift one kilogram of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, ideal-gas

I used the [Ideal Gas Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law) `PV = nRT` where

P is the pressure of the gas
P = 1.033 kgf/cm squared

V is the unknown volume of the gas

n is the amount of substance of gas (also known as number of moles)
n = 40.7 mole

R is the ideal, or universal, gas constant, equal to the product of the Boltzmann constant and the Avogadro constant.
R = [8.3145](http://www.csupomona.edu/~lllee/gasconstant.pdf)

T is the temperature of the gas
T = 298.15 K

**incorrect work snipped**

**UPDATE**

figured it out.

I used some of the work found here: http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/phy99/phy99471.htm

and then used ideal gas law against his answer to derive a volume of 266 gallons

I then used density = mass / volume against his answer and achieved similar results so as to feel confident that 266 gallons is correct at SATP

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's a calculator specifically for this problem http://keyvanfatehi.com/balloon

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/keyvanfatehi/balloon

It uses https://www.npmjs.org/package/gas-density-calculator and https://www.npmjs.org/package/archimedes-principle

Comment: It is advisable to FIRST convert all quantities to the proper units that you want to end up with, and then do the calculation. You also seem to have some numbers wrong ($R=8.3145$, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, updated. Also this is not homework, I am not in school--I just want to use math instead of using trial and error, and build some open source JavaScript code to help people understand factors at play....

Comment: That doesn't matter; the homework pertains to a certain type of question rather than the motivation of the asker ;)

Comment: Well this question is "On Hold" but I've solved it myself in two ways. One way was with Ideal Gas Law, the other was by applying this equality: density = mass / volume against this answer http://www.newton.dep.anl.gov/askasci/phy99/phy99471.htm . At SATP it will take 266 gallons to lift 1kg

Comment: https://github.com/keyvanfatehi/archimedes-principle

Comment: html calculator ---- http://keyvanfatehi.com/balloon/ ----- source code: https://github.com/keyvanfatehi/balloon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to approach this is to note that the [molar volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_volume) of an ideal gas (helium and air are close to ideal at STP) is $22.4$ litres. This means that $22.4$ litres of helium weighs $4$g and similarly $22.4$ litres of air (average $M_W = 28.8$) weighs $28.8$g.

[Archimedes' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) tells us that the upthrust is equal to the weight of fluid displaced, so when $22.4$ litres of helium displaces $22.4$ litres of air the net upthrust (weight of air - weight of helium) is $28.8 - 4 = 24.8$g.

From this you should be able to work out what volume of helium is required to produce an upthrust of $1$kg.